Steps to populate dynamic dropdown from API in React
I am trying to build a dropdown from the data returned in API response. The API response looks like this:
{"departments": ["Admin","HR","IT","OPS","Accounts"]}

The retrieval is being in this manner. I need help in accessing the data in the form of a dropdown within <div>

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select';

function Dropdown() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([{}])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/listDepartments").then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
        setData(data)
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
     <Select options={data.departments} />
    </div>
  )
}
export default Dropdown;

Error
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'options' in Admin
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'options' in Admin

What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? What kind of "dropdown", even (just a regular <select>, for example)?

Also if you are just fetching ..  You can scrap the useEffect altogether and just import and stringify() -- Please read: You Might Not Need An Effect -- useEffect can cause unnecessary re-renders .. Causing bloat and overhead.

try this:
function Dropdown() {
  // here, just default it to `[]`
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/listDepartments")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // put the departments data in the state
        setData(data.departments);
        console.log(data.departments);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* now you can map like this */}
      <select id="select">
        {data.map((e) => (
          <option key={e} value={e}>
            {e}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Dropdown;

If you want a real dropdown, well you have to do write it from scratch or try to use https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/dropdown-menu

this does print the data, can you help me put this in a dropdown

excellent and works fine but my joy is short lived because same approach is not working for another dropdown which returns the value from database in this manner {"nodePartition": "{"0":"Integrations","1":"Test"}"}. Is there a difference in data structure?

@ShivayanMukherjee You will need JSON.parse(data.nodePartition) and this becomes an plain object. previous departments is a simple one-dimensional array (no nested objects, just simple strings).

@ShivayanMukherjee This great docs can help you with JavaScript: https://javascript.info/


I've included a link to the documentation. Please follow the
instructions in the document. If you need to create a dropdown, ensure
that the array contains an array of objects.
enter link description hereenter link description here

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

function Dropdown() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/listDepartments")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const departments = data.departments.map(department => ({
          label: department,
          value: department
        }));
        setOptions(departments);
        console.log(departments);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Select options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dropdown;

In this code:

The options state now holds an array of objects, where each object
has label and value properties containing the department name.
Inside the useEffect hook, we map over the array of department names
(data.departments) and create objects with label and value
properties.
We then set the transformed array of objects as the options state.
Finally, we pass the options state to the Select component as the
options pro


excellent and works fine but my joy is short lived because same approach is not working for another dropdown which returns the value from database in this manner {"nodePartition": "{"0":"Integrations","1":"Test"}"}. Is there a difference in data structure?

Array.map() is supposed to take an Array. It would help to see what the code looks like, that gave you this error. From the error message i assumeyou are using it like data.map() so you are giving it an object.
I propose:
function Dropdown() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]) //just take an array in the state

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/listDepartments").then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
        setData(data.departments) //get the array from key departments
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <select name="departement">
          {data.map((value) => {
              return (
                  <option key={value} value={value}> 
                      {value} 
                  </option>
              )
          })}
        </select>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Dropdown;


You're answer is good, but the original question is looking to use the react-select package, whilst your solution using standard HTML components

The original question was edited. Before the question was: how to get data into any dropdown, providing an empty div. The question updates for every new Error the op gets while following the proposed solutions. I'm thankfull for your feedback nontheless, new to the platform and happy about every interaction
